# Joining tables using more than one column in Linq To Entities

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

Every single example of joins in Linq to Entities involves only one column in the `on` clause. What is the syntax if I need 2 or more columns to make the `join` work? I would need an example for Linq to Entities Query Expressions and Method Based also, if possible. Below is the example of what I need. There isn't a relationship between Table1 and Table2.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1 (
  ID1Table1 INT NOT NULL,
  ID2Table1 SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL,
  Value1Table1 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Table1 PRIMARY KEY (ID1Table1, ID2Table1));
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table2 (
  ID1Table2 INT NOT NULL,
  ID2Table2 SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL,
  ID3Table2 INT NOT NULL,
  Value1Table2 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Table2 PRIMARY KEY (ID1Table2, ID2Table2, ID3Table2));

SELECT a.ID1Table1, a.ID2Table1, a.Value1Table1, b.ID3Table2, b.Value1Table2
FROM dbo.Table1 a JOIN dbo.Table2 b
  ON a.ID1Table1 = b.ID1Table2
  AND a.ID2Table1 = b.ID2Table2
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can write it using two from expressions like below:

```
from a in Table1s 
from b in Table2s
where a.ID1Table1 == b.ID1Table2 && a.ID2Table1 == b.ID2Table2
select new {a.ID1Table1, a.ID2Table1, a.Value1Table1, b.ID3Table2, b.Value1Table2}
```

Using join:

```
from a in Table1s
join b in Table2s on new{PropertyName1 = a.ID1Table1, PropertyName2 = a.ID2Table1} equals new{PropertyName1 = b.ID1Table2, PropertyName2 = b.ID2Table2}
select new {a.ID1Table1, a.ID2Table1, a.Value1Table1, b.ID3Table2, b.Value1Table2}
```

Comment: Ok, tks. I will solve my problem, but I would really like to know how to accomplish this is using the join, in Query Expression and Method-Based.

Comment: Man, worked like a charm! Tks sooooooooo much... couldn't find this anywhere... The same concept applies to Lambda, right?

Comment: @Chandu is it true that the former style can use inequality (!=), but the latter cannot? In my case I want to find the inner join product where a column `Value` is different between tables, like: `where a.ID1Table1 == b.ID1Table2 && a.ID2Table1 == b.ID2Table2 && a.Value != b.Value`

Comment: If any body is interested in the documentation here it is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/join-by-using-composite-keys
they call it "Join by using composite keys"

Comment: Are those single `=`'s correct?

Answer (score 29):

For method based query:

```
var query = ctx.Table1s.Join(ctx.Table2s,
  a => new { a.ID1Table1, a.ID2Table1 },
  b => new { b.ID1Table2, b.ID2Table2 },
  (t1, t2) => new {
  t1.ID1Table1, t1.ID2Table1, t1.Value1Table1, t2.ID3Table2, t2.Value1Table2
});
```

if happen to be key column name is different between two tables, then should assign a same propery name in outer and inner selector. eg:

```
var query = ctx.Table1s.Join(ctx.Table2s,
  a => new { key1 = a.ID1Table1, key2 = a.ID2Table1 },
  b => new { key1 = b.ID1Table2, key2 = b.ID2Table2 },
  (t1, t2) => new {
    t1.ID1Table1, t1.ID2Table1, t1.Value1Table1, t2.ID3Table2, t2.Value1Table2
});
```

to verify the above query, print the sql statement:

```
string sql = ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)query).ToTraceString();
```

Comment: The comment about naming difference applies to type difference too (e.g. when joining `int` and `int?` is needed)