# Automatically link objects using computation on fields with Entity Framework or SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have two "entities", Job Code and Job Family:

```
public class JobCode{
    public int Code {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class JobFamily{
    public int Code {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

`JobCode.Code` is a 5-digit code, and `JobFamily.Code` is 2 digits, which correspond with the first 2 digits of a Job Code, so there is an intrinsic relationship that I would like to capture in either the code or the database.

If I use code-first Entity Framework (or if I use database-first), is there a way to get something like:

```
CREATE TABLE JobFamily
(
    Code int PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(255)
);
CREATE TABLE JobCode
(
    Code int PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(255),
    JobFamily AS (Code / 1000) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES JobFamily(Code)
);
```

Is this even possible in SQL Server?  I can't find anything saying it's not, but I can't find anyone trying to do it either...

Comment: If Sql Server can't do it (which it can't), EF can't do it.

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible to set a foreign key constraint on a computed column.

Comment: in sql you could create the computed column, it just won't be a foreign key reference.  you can still join on it though (in sql, not sure about entity framework)

Comment: ok, according to this you can join using linq:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4736362/95710